# Problema al cargar librarias en R . Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR

Tags: r, librería

Soy nueva en R y soy nueva en este foro. Espero que me puedan ayudar. :)

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en R y todo iba bien (con los problemas típicos de una principiante) pero hoy he actualizado algunas librerias, y los paquetes y el código que hasta hoy funcionaba bien, ahora R no me deja utilizarlos.

Ahora, cuando quiero cargar una libreria, me sale este error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’ in dyn.load(file,
> DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so,
> 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so
> Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
> in
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so

Me sale el mismo error para distintos paquetes, cuando hasta hoy me funcionaban bien: "raster", "spData", y "tmap". He intentado desinstalar los paquetes y volverlos a instalar, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo problema.

Estoy trabajando en R desde un Mac.

Alguien tiene idea de lo que me puede ocurrir y cómo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida marisantpere a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Has actualizado la versión de R últimamente? ¿algún cambio en el sistema operativo? ¿has probado instalar `raster` nuevamente? `install.packages("raster")`

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido solucionar desinstalando R y Rstudio y volviendolo a instalar todo. El problema me salió al actualizar algunos paquetes, pero me estraña que eso ocurra cada vez que actualizo algun paquete, no?

Comment: Que bueno que lo hayas solucionado. Con una instalación limpia de cero no debería pasarte nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

También tuve el mismo error y leyendo creo que también está asociado a una actualización de la paquetería Rcpp, que no puedo actualizar. Ambos problemas los solucioné actualizando a la versión 4.0.2.